# Why doesn't **find** find anything?

Tags: bash, unix, shell, ksh

I'm looking for shell scripts files installed on my system, but **find** doesn't work:

```
$ find /usr -name *.sh
```

But I know there are a ton of scripts out there.  For instance:

```
$ ls /usr/local/lib/*.sh
/usr/local/lib/tclConfig.sh  
/usr/local/lib/tkConfig.sh
```

Why doesn't **find** work?

Comment: Is this a SuperUser question?

Comment: This fits better on [UnixSE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Try quoting the wildcard:

```
$ find /usr -name \*.sh
```

or:

```
$ find /usr -name '*.sh'
```

If you happen to have a file that matches ***.sh** in the current working directory, the wildcard will be expanded before find sees it.  If you happen to have a file named tkConfig.sh in your working directory, the **find** command would expand to:

```
$ find /usr -name tkConfig.sh
```

which would only find files named tkConfig.sh.  If you had more than one file that matches ***.sh**, you'd get a syntax error from **find**:

```
$ cd /usr/local/lib
$ find /usr -name *.sh
find: bad option tkConfig.sh
find: path-list predicate-list
```

Again, the reason is that the wildcard expands to both files:

```
$ find /usr -name tclConfig.sh tkConfig.sh
```

Quoting the wildcard prevents it from being prematurely expanded.

Another possibility is that /usr or one of its subdirectories is a symlink.  **find** doesn't normally follow links, so you might need the **-follow** option:

```
$ find /usr -follow -name '*.sh'
```

Comment: What if the file is a shell script but lacks the `.sh` extension? Maybe something like `find /xyz | xargs file | grep shell`?

Comment: How often, though, do shell scripts **not** have a .sh extension?

Comment: Is there any general way to figure out when/where a wildcard is being expanded?

Comment: Well, growing up in windows where *everything* has an extension I've seen quite a lot scripts on *ix omitting that `.sh`

Answer (score 15):

On some systems (Solaris, for example), there's no default action, so you need to add the -print command.

```
find /usr -name '*.foo' -print
```

Comment: I've been bit by that in the past. But I should point out that on a modern Solaris box, -print is on by default. In fact, I can't seem to find a find that doesn't work that way any more.

Answer (score 8):

For finding files on your disks, lean to use "locate" instead that is instantaneous
(looks into a daily built index)
you example would be:

```
locate '/usr*.sh'
```

Comment: A fine suggestion.  (I had to run updatedb on my machine to test the idea, since I don't have it in my crontab for some reason.  Not having an up-to-date database would be the main reason to not use locate.)

Comment: And there are a few systems that don't have locate installed by default - I found I had to install the `mlocate` package on my Raspberry Pi - not forgetting the `sudo updatedb` afterwards to build the indexes...