# A question about command "find"

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

```
find . \( -name "_*" -or -newer while2 \) -type f -print
```

In the linux command above , why _* should  be quoted ?

Comment: A similar question: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18836/why-doesnt-find-find-anything>

Answer (score 9):

First, the shell expands all unquoted *'s to match file names in the local directory.

After that, the shell runs the `find` command with that list of file names.

Generally, you don't want the shell to do '*' globbing in the local directory.  Generally, you wind the find command to do filename matching in other directories.

The shell has several other things it does before running a command.  $VARIABLE replacement is one of those.

Answer (score 5):

> Why _* should be quoted ?

If it isn't, your shell might expand the `*` to be substituted with files in the current directory. That's probably not what you wanted here.

Comment: Right, because the find command will expand the * glob operator.

Comment: the problem is that the shell expands it before the find command gets it

Answer (score 2):

if you don't quote it, the shell (bash?) would try to expand.  if there's any file that starts with '`_`' on the current directory, you'd get something like:

```
find . \(-name _somefile _someother _file3 .... -or -newer while2 \) -type f -print
```

certainly not what you want.  i always quote patterns, just to be sure the shell won't mess with them

Comment: When I use find . -name c*,it find fewer matches than find . -name "c*". Why?

Comment: probably you have a singe file that starts with c, and the find command gets you all files with the exact same name, instead of other names that start with c